# js - check if a function is completed

Tags: javascript, function

I want to set a hotkey to several functions by jquery hotkeys. And I need to check if a function is finished, may be something like:

```
if("function A is completed")
{
    "Ctrl+A is now set to function B"
}
else
{
    "Ctrl+A is set to function A"
}
```

How could I check this? Or any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript on web browsers is single-threaded (barring the use of web workers, and even with those a function can't be interrupted), so except for a couple of <s>bugs in</s> *issues* with Firefox, a function *cannot* be interrupted in the middle. So if your code is running, the other function is not, by definition.

(For details on the issues with Firefox, see [this answer by bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded) about some very edge-case scenarios.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation there are a couple of things you can do. You can call the function when you've finished completing the current function or you can set a boolean for the same thing.

```
function A(){
  alert('run items in function A');
  return fireNewFunctionWhenComplete()
}
```

or set a flag

```
/*global var*/
var functionBCompleted = false;

function B(){
  alert('run items in function B');
   return functionBCompleted = true;  
}

function testFunctionComplete(){
  if(functionBCompleted){
    alert('function B Copmleted');
  }
  else{
    alert('function B not run');
  }
}
```

This is a very simple example and as @T.J. mentioned you can't interrupt a running process. However, you may want to take a look into the promises spec if you want to run something when an asynchronous operation has completed.